# What's the Bash equivalent of "cmd /c"

Tags: bash, cygwin, cmd.exe

I'm trying to launch a Bash Shell window that should immediately start a Windows Application. It's the Bash Equivalent of "cmd /c MyApplication.exe". MyApplication is a Windows Console application.

I tried a couple of things that do not seem to work. Or just result in a hanging bash shell...

```
 sh.exe --login -I MyApplication.exe
 sh.exe MyApplication.exe
```

Creating a `MyApplication.sh` that starts `MyApplication.exe` seems to work, but is not desireable, as I'd like to include the start-up script in a debug macro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Bash equivalent is `bash -c <command>`. This information is easily found in the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash).

This, for example, is what is used when you enter a custom command for a SSH session.

Now, you do need to keep in mind that Bash is not a Windows shell. If `<command>` is located in your working directory, you need to invoke it as `./<command>`.

If you just toss it the file as the first argument, Bash will try to execute it as a Bash script.

Also, if you really want Bash, use `bash`. `sh` could be anything.

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for the `sh.exe` pages, but that didn't help. The combination of `-c` and `./` did the trick.

Comment: `bash -c` only works for single argument command lines. `cmd /c echo hello world` prints "hello world" but `bash -c echo hello world` prints nothing. You can run `bash -c "echo hello world"`, but this gets problematic when your arguments contains spaces and/or quotes.

Answer (score 1):

End the command with a `&` like this

```
sh.exe MyApplication.exe &
```

Comment: To expand on that: the reason this works with cmd is that it has hacks to detect that the application being started is a gui one and fake the return code rather than waiting for the process to actually terminate and return a status.

Answer (score 0):

In Cygwin, you might investigate `cygstart` in the 'cygutils' package.

From the man page:

> Let Windows start a program or open a file or URL.

<...>

> EXAMPLES

```
  Start Bash in a new window

   $ cygstart bash

   Open the Cygwin website in your default browser:

   $ cygstart http://www.cygwin.com

   Print a text file

   $ cygstart --print README.txt

   Open a Word document in a maximized window

   $ cygstart --maximize ~/projects/whatever/design.doc
```

Try `cygstart --help`