# How to run a Windows batch process in background, but kill it if the command prompt is closed?

Tags: linux, windows, command-line, batch, prompt

On Linux, I could do this just doing:

```
myprogram &
```

However on Windows... If I start a command like:

```
start /B myprogram.exe
```

It runs in the background, but if I close my command prompt, the `myprogram.exe` is not killed. How to make it be killed automatically when the command prompt is closed?

Related question:

1. [Windows - Run process on background after closing cmd](https://superuser.com/questions/1069972/windows-run-process-on-background-after-closing-cmd)

Comment: Use `cmd /c` command before it.

Comment: I tried `cmd /c npm run watch`, but the console still locked into the node process. Did you mean `cmd /c start /B npm run watch`? Update, I tried this last one and worked! What magic is this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the Bash equivalent of "cmd /c"](https://superuser.com/questions/860833/whats-the-bash-equivalent-of-cmd-c)

Comment: `start` doesn't make the program "run in the background". It makes it run as a child of the desktop process. There are equivaments in Linux desktop environments (`kstart` for KDE, for instance).

Comment: @user `start /b` command starts application without creating a new window.

Comment: But if the current window is closed, the application does not die. Which is the opposite on the linux `commmand &` which start the application, but if the window closes, the application closes also.

Comment: of course it cannot die, because as others has said multiple times, **`start /b` doesn't start the process in background** and just starts a process that doesn't belong to the current console